# HTML5 canvas artifacts

Tags: vue.js, html5-canvas

I have created a Vue component that loads an image into a canvas and allows the user to zoom-in and zoom-out with the mouse wheel. The image resolution is 1260x1800, the canvas resolution is 427x610 (the aspect ratio is preserved).

```js
<template>
  <canvas
    ref="canvas"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
    @mousedown.prevent.stop="onMouseDown"
    @mousemove.prevent.stop="onMouseMove"
    @mouseup.prevent.stop="onMouseUp"
    @mouseout.prevent.stop="onMouseOut"
    @mousewheel.prevent.stop="onMouseWheel"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyZoomingCanvas',

  props: {
    src: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },

    zoom: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
      validator: zoom =>
        zoom &&
        zoom.hasOwnProperty('min') &&
        zoom.hasOwnProperty('max') &&
        zoom.hasOwnProperty('step') &&
        zoom.hasOwnProperty('scale')
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      img: null,
      isMouseDown: false,
      startX: null,
      startY: null,
      dx: 0,
      dy: 0,
      width: 427,
      height: 610
    }
  },

  watch: {
    'zoom.scale'() {
      this.draw()
    }
  },

  methods: {
    draw() {
      const canvas = this.$refs.canvas
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height)
      ctx.setTransform(
        this.zoom.scale,
        0,
        0,
        this.zoom.scale,
        ((1 - this.zoom.scale) * this.width) / 2,
        ((1 - this.zoom.scale) * this.height) / 2
      )

      ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0, this.width, this.height)
    },

    loadImage(src) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const img = new Image()
        img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(img))
        img.addEventListener('error', err => reject(err))
        img.src = src
      })
    },

    onMouseDown({ clientX, clientY }) {
      this.startX = clientX
      this.startY = clientY

      this.isMouseDown = true
    },

    onMouseMove({ clientX, clientY }) {
      if (this.isMouseDown) {
        this.dx += clientX - this.startX
        this.dy += clientY - this.startY

        this.draw()

        this.startX = clientX
        this.startY = clientY
      }
    },

    onMouseUp() {
      this.isMouseDown = false

      this.dx = 0
      this.dy = 0
    },

    onMouseOut() {
      this.isMouseDown = false
    },

    onMouseWheel({ offsetX, offsetY, deltaY }) {
      this.dx = -offsetX
      this.dy = -offsetY

      this.$emit(
        'scale-change',
        Math.min(this.zoom.max, Math.max(this.zoom.min, this.zoom.scale - deltaY * this.zoom.step))
      )
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.loadImage(this.src).then(img => {
      this.img = img

      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.draw()
      })
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

I noticed that in some cases the images are affected by strange artifacts, take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/lmartini/b3hLr5ej/latest/

**In the example, while zooming-in, I can clearly see a bunch of horizontal bands along the whole fabric height that disappear after a certain zoom level.**

By googling I believe that these artifacts are caused by the resolution mismatch between the canvas and the image (the so called *pixel-perfect* problem) and, hence, by the internal browser downsampling algorithm.
I tried to improve the image smoothing quality of the canvas by adding the following lines but they didn't make any difference at all (my target browser is Chrome):

```js
// ctx is the canvas context
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true
ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high'
```

How can I get rid of these artifacts?

Comment: They are a type of Moiré pattern, in this case caused by rendering a large image with a regular repeating pattern at low resolution. You need to create copies of the image at lower resolutions using a high quality down sampler (eg photoshop, gimp, or write one in JS) then render the image that is nearest the zoom resolution (similar to mip maps as used in 3D)